# How do I attach a Vivitar wide angle lens to my Nikon d3200?

Tags: lens, wide-angle, nikon-d3200, vivitar

I've just bought a Nikon D3200. It included a Vivitar Series 1 high-definition 0.43X 52mm wide angle lens (along with a 18-55mm f/3.5-5.6 auto focus-S DX VR Nikkor zoom lens).  I really have no idea how to attach the included wide angle lens.  Do I need an adapter?

Answer (score 2):

...I just answered my question about the macro/ wide angle lens - you just screw it on to the end of the zoom lens :)